# C ++ library Cross compiling

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to cross compile a c++ library to the android plateform and this library depends on other libraries (those librairies are included yet in the android plateform).

Actually ,i have downloaded the android source code (android 4.1), i have also the library source code and i just don't know how to cross compile this library with it dependencies?
I would be thankfull if someone can tell me the right way to do it.

Comment: Did you mean "are included yet" or "are **not** included yet?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the easiest path is to set up the [standalone toolchain](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html) using latest Android NDK, and build your library and all its dependencies with that toolchain. Here is an example: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingForAndroid